# Concatenating 2 objects into a dictionary value

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, dictionary

I have the following code, that creates a dictionary:

```
branches.ToDictionary(row => row.Field<object>(1), row => row.Field<object>(3)).ToList();
```

I want to create the dictionary value as `row.Field<object>(3) + row.Field<object>(4)`. I think I'm looking for some kind of a concat method, but none seem to be available. Will I have to loop through each element individually?

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate"? Are these values strings as you are reading them as `object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the types of `row.Field<object>(3)` and `row.Field<object>(4)` are `string`, then read them as strings and `+` them together (or perhaps use `string.Format` or `string.Concat`):

```
branches.ToDictionary(
    row => row.Field<object>(1), 
    row => row.Field<string>(3) + row.Field<string>(4)
).ToList();
```

If they are really `object` or two types that you just want paired together, you can add them as a tuple, or preferably create a class to hold them. For example:

```
public class IntAndString //Choose a better name than this!
{
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

And then project the values into the class:

```
branches.ToDictionary(
    row => row.Field<object>(1), 
    row => new IntAndString
           {
               IntValue = row.Field<int>(3),
               StringValue = row.Field<string>(4)
           }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concat them, but if these are string-columns use `Field<string>`(preferred) or `ToString`:

```
branches.ToDictionary(
    row => row.Field<object>(1), 
    row => row.Field<string>(3) + row.Field<string>(4))
        .ToList();
```

In general use the correct type instead always `object`.

Another way if you only have objects is to use [`String.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
branches.ToDictionary(
    row => row.Field<object>(1), 
    row => String.Concat(row.Field<object>(3), row.Field<object>(4)))
        .ToList();
```